# Frequent internet disruption

Tags: router, dsl-modem, adsl2+, crc

I am getting disconnected from internet very frequently. The router and the computer connection is stable but the router blinking stops -> becomes red -> and then starts blinking again. I did a little bit of searching and have found that I need to look into the following stats. However I am not able to understand these images.

1. Whenever I am getting the internet disruption, the following is the DSL start stats

[image]

2. After an uptime of 1 hr 12min, this is the status page [dsl status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPv6.png)

[image]

Is it the CRC errors and the SNR margin that are problematic here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy as you mentioned it might just be a problem with your ISP. Just try contacting them via helpline number and tell them this problem.
I also suffered from the same problem recently and technician came and changed my connection line and from that day my Internet is working flawlessly.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that.